# I can't understand the fundemantals of functions in python

Tags: python

```
word = input('enter a word:')
letter = input('enter the letter you want to count:')
number = 0

def count(word ,letter)  :
    for i in word :
        if i == letter :
            number = number + 1
    print(number)

count(word ,letter)
```

this script doesn't work but this one works:

```
word = input('enter a word:')
letter = input('enter the letter you want to count:')

def count(word ,letter)  :
    number = 0
    for i in word :
        if i == letter :
            number = number + 1
    print(number)

count(word ,letter)
```

When `number = 0` is replaced, why is the code affected?
What is the thing that is I don't know about fuctions?
What is the difference between `number = 0` in function and out of function?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Are you talking about the "referenced before assignment error" that occurs in the second code? Please be clear about what you're asking.

Comment: `What is the thing that is I don't know` - it's called *scope*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign (i.e. re-assign) values to variables defined outside of the function (you can however manipulate them, so if it's an object such as a list or a dict, you can modify that object - but again, that's not recommended as it makes code hard to read).

Keep all necessary references inside the function (and send any required information in as arguments to that function).

What you're actually asking about isn't only about functions, but it's what's called **scope**. Scope defines what symbols (which variables, etc.) are visible to code in particular locations.